# How to configure ehcache to replace expired object only upon successfully retrieving a newer version of the object

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Currently I am using Spring web framework for my Web App. I have implemented a basic CacheConfig.java file that reads ehcache.xml and that creates a CacheManager and is used to get an element from cache or adds an element to cache. My ehcache.cml is as follows:

```
    <cache name="Cache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="100"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="0"
       eternal="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="0"
       timeToIdleSeconds="43200"
       timeToLiveSeconds="43200"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       >
    <persistence strategy="none"/>
```

How can I ensure that cache is refreshed by first looking for the object from the backend database(SOR) and only on successful retrieval does the older version of the element get removed?

**EDIT**: CacheLoader for refreshahead strategy .

```
public class TestCacheLoader implements CacheLoader {
@Override
public Object load(Object key) throws CacheException {
    //return null;
    return load(key,null);


}

@Override
public Map loadAll(Collection keys) {
    //return null;
    return loadAll(keys,null);
}

@Override
public Object load(Object key, Object argument) {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
       obj = ReadFromDatabase(key);
    } catch (DatabaseValueNotFoundException e) {
      **How can I return the old value here?**
    }
    return obj;
}

@Override
public Map loadAll(Collection keys, Object argument) {
    //return null;
    Map newValues = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
    for(Object key : keys){
        Object value = load(key,null);
        if(value != null){
            newValues.put(key,value);
        }
    }
    return newValues;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public CacheLoader clone(Ehcache ehcache) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void init() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() throws CacheException {

}

@Override
public Status getStatus() {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box support for doing what you ask.

Ehcache 2.x has support for [refresh ahead](http://documentation.softwareag.com/onlinehelp/Rohan/terracotta_434/bigmemory-max/webhelp/index.html#page/bigmemory-max-webhelp%2Fto-refresh_ahead.html%23) which can be further tweaked with [scheduled refresh ahead](http://documentation.softwareag.com/onlinehelp/Rohan/terracotta_434/bigmemory-max/webhelp/index.html#page/bigmemory-max-webhelp%2Fco-refresh_scheduled_refresh_ahead.html%23wwconnect_header). It is not exactly what you are asking but might be close enough.

** Additions after the question was edited **

What your edit suggests is that you want to keep a stale value, since the DB no longer has an entry for that key, instead of telling the user there is no value. Here again there is no support for that as it goes against the principle of a cache.

Comment: Please see my edit. I don't understand how to return the older value in the cache as cacheloader has no access to values in the cache it loads values for.